# Is there any generic API on android to set a new font on anyforeground windows textview or editor

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am looking to find if there is any way to set a font on foreground windows textbox or editor on android.
ex like what we have sendmessage or postmessage on windows we can send a font in these and system applies that font to the specified window. Is there anything similar on android?

Comment: If this is your own UI, the framework you are using for creating that UI should allow for font control (e.g., `Typeface` options on `TextView`). If you are trying to attack another app's UI, then this is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses styles and themes to set look and feel. You can set a theme at the application level, activity level, or for individual views. Modify `AndroidManifest.xml` to set themes at the application or activity level. All of it is described in: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Theme. It includes detailed sample code and should take no more than 15 to read and implement.

In your theme you can include a font to use. Fonts can be easily defined in XML starting at API level 26 (easily compared to how you needed to do it before API 26). The details can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml. In that documentation it will tell you how to set a font and apply it to an individual view or to a style. This reading should also take no longer than 15 minutes and includes detailed sample code.

Your steps will be, after just reading the above two official Android docs, to 1) define your font, 2) set the font in a style. 3) use the style as a theme and set your application or activity to use that theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you set your theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`. And by reading the docs, you'll be a master at defining and implementing different levels of themes!